# How to clear any column sorting in PickList

Tags: lotus-notes, lotusscript

Does any of you know how to clear any column sorting before opening a view in a picklist?

I have a view with columns that can be sorted if they are clicked.
The  information about the view is now sorted by a column is kept.

If I change away from the view and click on my button which includes a picklist that shows the view. Then the column sorting is remembered.

How can clear any column sorting in the view?
I have tried the method resortview but can’t get that to work.

Comment: Wow. I had no idea. I guess you could avoid it by having hidden views for all your picklists....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can disable this in your Notes Preferences. 
Choose from menu File - Preferences - Basic Notes Client Configuration and disable the option "Retain View column sorting"
Caution: This setting affects any Lotus Notes Database, it is a global setting for your Notes client.